# vps nameserver setup not working

Tags: dns, vps, whm

I am a noob in the VPS-DNS world.

I purchased a VPS (with one ip) and logged into WHM to setup for production. I configured nameservers to "ns1.a-domain-i-have.com" and "ns2.a-domain-i-have.com". 
Then logged into that domain account at my register where I 
- set default nameservers from the registrar
- in DNS manager I set ns1, A , my server IP and ns2, A, the same server IP
After creating a host account in WHM using "another-domain-I-have.com", I registered "ns1.a-domain-i-have.com" and "ns2.a-domain-i-have.com" in the custom nameservers.

But my new website refuse to work/ nothing works, I did all these based on the understanding of tutorials I googled.

**I have tried**
- reinstalled the VPS
- used the default nameserver that came with the VPS host. Although, this nameserver ip is unknown.
- update cPanel

I need some help!

Comment: I already got it. It works now. The steps I mentioned aboved did it. Maybe am supposed to take this down but I'll leave it for newbies like me.

Comment: Perhaps tell us what steps you did worked and why, so others who have the same issue may benefit from the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I already got it. It works now. The steps I mentioned aboved did it. Maybe am supposed to take this down but I'll leave it for newbies like me.